# Regex: Capture Groups within quotes and outside of quotes as well

Tags: regex

I am building a Regex that should work like this:

If I have a string

`testing my regex "testing 1234" asdf 'asdfasd'`

I would like to get the groups:

```
testing my regex
"testing 1234"
asdf
'asdfasd'
```

Currently I have built the regex:

`(^[^\"]*)\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'`
Testable here: https://regex101.com/r/NkRTzh/1/

Which, on the same string, returns:

```
testing my regex "testing 1234"
'asdfasd'
```

How could I modify my regex such that I can get my desired result. I should mention that I am using this In python, hence the quote escaping.

Comment: If you need the quotes, you may try `re.split(r"""("[^"]*"|'[^']*')""")`

Comment: Doesn't that only match the phrases within the quotes? Whereas I would like the phrases in the quotes (with quotes) and the non quoted segments.

Comment: [It does not match, it ***splits***](http://rextester.com/KODT4250)

Comment: Doh! Thanks so much for this! If you submit it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Posted with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tokenize a string like this, it might be a better idea to use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) with a regex containing a capturing group around the pattern part that you would also want to output in the resulting array. See the docs:

> If capturing parentheses are used in *pattern*, then the **text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list**.

Here, use

```
re.split(r"""("[^"]*"|'[^']*')""")
```

See [Python demo](http://rextester.com/TPQ15471):

```
import re
s= """testing my regex "testing 1234" asdf 'asdfasd'"""
print(re.split(r"""("[^"]*"|'[^']*')""",s))
# => ['testing my regex ', '"testing 1234"', ' asdf ', "'asdfasd'", '']
print(filter(None, re.split(r"""("[^"]*"|'[^']*')""",s)))
# => ['testing my regex ', '"testing 1234"', ' asdf ', "'asdfasd'"]
```

With `filter(None, list)` you may easily remove empty entries that are always present when consecutive matches are found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
^([^\"]+(\".+\")([^\"']+)('.+'))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/NkRTzh/4/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
\s*((\")|(')|\b)([^'\"]+)((?(2)\"|(?(3)'|(?<=\w))))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kN7hvR/8)

- capture groups for desired output : group 1, 4, 5 (or \1, \4, \5)
- capture groups for checking quote : group 2, 3   (or \2, \3)

Replace with  `\1\4\5\n`

```
testing my regex
"testing 1234"
asdf
'asdfasd'
```

As you can see, this regex uses conditionals `(?(n) ... | ,,, )` which checks if `n-th` capture group was captured and if so, match the `...` pattern, otherwise match the `,,,` pattern. I think this conditionals is especially useful in some cases like this which needs matching pairwise for quotation marks(`' ', " "`), brackets, parenthesis, braces, etc.